# Javascript Calculation - NaN message

Tags: javascript, math, random, generator, nan

Would someone be able to help me with this. When i attempt calculations in Javascript they always seem to fail and come back as NaN

```
function SpinRand()
{

    var a,b,c,d,e,f;

    a=Math.floor(Math.random()*9);

    b=Math.floor(Math.random()*9);

    c=Math.floor(Math.random()*9);

    d=Math.floor(Math.random()*9);

    e=Math.floor(Math.random()*9);

    f=a+b+c+d+e+f;

    alert(f);

}
```

Comment: If you want 5 digits between 0 and 9, you can do `var f=[];
while (f.length<5) f.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*9))
return f.join("")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do

```
f=a+b+c+d+e+f;
```

you're adding a few numbers to `f`, which is `undefined`. This makes `NaN`.

You probably want

```
f=a+b+c+d+e;
```

and maybe

```
return f;
```

at the end too.

Note that your function could be better written using a loop :

```
var f = 0;
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) f+=Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
```

Comment: Ahh thanks. Accidentally was trying to add f as well.